# Java Predicates with distributive law

Tags: java, predicate

I have a boolean Java statement that is structured like follows:

return A **AND** (B **OR** C **OR** D)

In Java:

```java
return A && (B || C || D);
```

I wanted to reformulate this by using chained predicates, but it seems like I have to use the distributive law of Boolean algebra in order to make it work:

(A **AND** B) **OR** (A **AND** C) **OR** (A **AND** D) which forces me to repeat A all the time.

This is what I ended up with in java:

```java
return A.and(B)
        .or(A.and(C))
        .or(A.and(D))
        .test(params)
```

This seems not to lead to the same results, as my test cases fail when I'm using the predicate version.

Is this not possible with Java Predicates without making use of the distributive law or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why not `A.and(B.or(C).or(D)).test(params)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your statement exactly as you want to:

```java
A.and(B.or(C).or(D))
```

### EDIT:

Here's an example for your question from the comments:

```
// here you tell Java that p1 is of type Predicate
// though you can use "and" and "or"
Predicate<String> p1 = s -> s.equals("foo");
p1.and(s -> !s.equals("bar"));
```

But you could also create your own functional interface with the same signature but different default methods:

```
public interface MyCustomPredicate<T> {
    boolean test(T value);

    default MyCustomPredicate<T> and(MyCustomPredicate<? super T> other) {
        return (t) -> true;
    }
}

// ...

// here you tell Java that p2 is of type MyCustomPredicate
// though you can't use "or"
// and MyCustomPredicate.and does not behave the same as Predicate.and
MyCustomPredicate p2 = s -> s.equals("bar");
p2.and(s -> !s.equals("bar"));
```

It's a bit different from pre-lambda Java. The signature of `Predicate.and` says that it accepts a `Predicate`. But in reality this means that it accepts **any** lambda that matches `T -> boolean`.

```
Predicate<String> p1 = s -> s.equals("foo");
MyCustomPredicate p2 = s -> s.equals("bar");
// this works because MyCustomPredicate has the same T -> boolean signature as Predicate
p1.or(p2);
```

You can cast lambdas inline as well:

```
Predicate<String> p3 = (s) -> true;
p3.and(((Predicate<String>) x -> true).and(x -> true));
```

Summarized: If you just write `s -> s.equals("bar")` Java doesn't know if this lambda is a `Predicate` or any other functional interface that has the same signature `T -> boolean`.

Comment: This worked, but only by making B an actual `Predicate`. When i type B as direct lambda predicate enclosed by paranthesis it does not work - the compiler says `lambda expression not expected here`. On the other hand, C and D don't have to be `Predicate` variables, they can be inserted directly as `(params) -> doStuff`. Seems like i do not understand the compiler here, can you please explain? I have looked at the signatures of `and` and `or` in the docs, but they seem equal to me x.x

Comment: If you just write a lambda without explicit typing, Java doesn't know what type to use. `and` and `or` are default methods within the `Predicate` interface. Though you must tell Java that your lambda is of type `Predicate` in order to use those methods.

Comment: Shouldnt Java know what type to use when A is already `Predicate` ?

Comment: I'll add some explanation to my answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to use pararenthesis

```
A.and(B.or(C).or(D));
```

And here is a verification.

```
Function<Boolean[], Boolean> pred = ar -> {
    Predicate<Boolean[]> A = a -> a[0];
    Predicate<Boolean[]> B = b -> b[1];
    Predicate<Boolean[]> C = c -> c[2];
    Predicate<Boolean[]> D = d -> d[3];
    return A.and(B.or(C).or(D)).test(ar);
};

Function<Boolean[], Boolean> java = arr -> {
    boolean A = arr[0];
    boolean B = arr[1];
    boolean C = arr[2];
    boolean D = arr[3];
    return A && (B || C || D);
};


Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
    Boolean[] b = Stream.generate(() -> r.nextBoolean())
            .limit(4).toArray(Boolean[]::new);  
    if (java.apply(b) != pred.apply(b)) {
        System.out.println("Different results");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're evaluating the predicate immediately after constructing it, you can evaluate all the terms:

```
return A.test(params)
    && (B.test(params) || C.test(params) || D.test(params));
```

which avoids creating objects that you discard almost immediately.

Comment: The JVM is heavily optimized to garbage collect objects that have a short life span. It's always better to write readable code, instead of premature optimization.

Comment: @BenjaminM merely pointing out an alternative.